# Hi..I have issue when I clicked on Upload file button, file uploading window not get open but its sometimes works,How I solved it?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Java.I have issue when I clicked on Upload file button, file uploading window not get open but its sometimes works,How I solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not click on file upload rather just use send keys..

```
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("myfile"));
upload.sendKeys("c:\\darkbulb.jpg");
```

**UPDATE:**

From the information shared you cannot use send keys as it works only for `<input type="file">`. So you must use Autoit,
1.Download and Install Autoit tool from http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/
2.Open Programs -> Autoit tool -> Script Editor.
3.Paste the following code in Autoit editor and save it as “filename.exe“ (eg: fileUpload.exe)

Then compile and build the file to make it exe. (Tools → Compile). Following is the code for autoit:

```
WinWaitActive("File Upload"); Name of the file upload window pop-up(Windows Popup Name: File Upload)    
Send("c:\logo.jpg"); File name (absolute path preferred)   
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Then Compile and Build from Tools menu

Use the below Java code to call autoit file

Java Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button")).click; // open the Upload window using selenium    
Thread.sleep("20000"); // wait for page load    
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Documents and Settings\\new.exe"); // Give  path where the exe is saved.
```

Comment: Hi, these syntax cant working for me Because there is only upload button that have to click & then window for file upload is open. Its working fine in Chrome & Fife Fox browser only issue in IE. Please give Solution.

Comment: @Swapnil If its a browse file button you can use `sendKeys`... have you tried the above command? what error u get ?

Comment: Yeah I tried, after executing these command whole page get refresh and file is not getting Uploaded.

Comment: @Swapnil can you confirm if the HTML code is `<input type="file">` ? because the above script would work only if so...

Comment: hi... Upload Button HTML code is <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">

Comment: @Swapnil I've updated my answer... this would work... you must use Aotoit for this task... let me know if you face any difficulty...